# Remove NSLog for release versions in Swift 4

Tags: swift

I would like to globally ignore all `NSLog` for release versions, and I found this method for objc:

```
#ifndef DEBUG
#define NSLog(s,...)
#endif
```

Is something like this in Swift 4? I just tried another post's solutions, but nothing worked because of the Swift version I think.

Comment: What did you try that didn't work? You need to [edit] your question to include all relevant code in the form of a [mcve] in order to make the question on-topic.

Comment: I'm curious why you're using NSLog at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#if DEBUG
    NSLog(s,...)
#endif
```